# How to change number of decimal points depending on value in a column?

Tags: r, decimal

I want to mutate "Result" to have the same number of decimal points as "Limit". Here's the dataframe:

| Limit | Result |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.1 |
| 1.2 | 1.35 |
| 1.55 | 1.681 |

For example if Limit=1.2, I want to update Result from 1.35 to 1.4.

I first created the "Decimal" column by:

```
mutate(Decimal = nchar(file_ext(as.character(Limit))))
```

| Limit | Result | Decimal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.1 | 0 |
| 1.2 | 1.35 | 1 |
| 1.55 | 1.681 | 2 |

And then I tried to use the round() function

```
mutate(Result=round(Result, digits=Decimal))
```

but it's not working. All results are rounded off with 1 decimal point.
Any advice will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you tag what language or technology you are using in addition to decimal ?is it python or R?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code below

```
transform(
    df,
    Result2 = round(Result, (Limit %% 1 != 0) * nchar(gsub(".*\\.", "", Limit)))
)
```

which gives

```
  Limit Result Result2
1  1.00  1.100    1.00
2  1.20  1.350    1.40
3  1.55  1.681    1.68
```

Comment: Elegant and concise.

Answer (score 1):

Another option which is a mixture of `tidyverse` and base R:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Result = case_when(
    grepl("\\.", Limit) ~ round(Result, nchar(unlist(strsplit(as.character(Limit), "\\."))[2])),
    TRUE ~ Limit
  ))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Rowwise: 
  Limit Result Decimal
  <dbl>  <dbl>   <int>
1  1      1          0
2  1.2    1.4        1
3  1.55   1.68       2
```